# Is there a way to force QGIS to use scaleable markers for map prints?

Tags: qgis, svg, filling

The implementation of scaleable vector graphs in QGIS is very cool, however, when svgs are used for point pattern fill of polygons, these markers are obviously rasterized, blowing up the filesize of pdf-prints tremendously..

This even happens with simple fill for polygons, i.e. polygon filling with diagonal lines, which will be rasterized for pdf-prints. The pdf-filesizes change a 10-fold when using these fill types.

Can anybody tell me if there is an option or workaround to force QGIS to use scaleable markers for map prints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is known and [reported in the upstream issue tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6996). There is no known workaround yet.

If you would like to solve this, please

- add information in the bugtracker
- consider implementing a patch and creating a pull request
- or hire/contract a developer to implement this fix

Comment: Thanks for the info! ..hope that there might be a fix someday.